# Android Facebook Code is deprecated not sure how to fix that - Solve

Tags: android, facebook, sdk

I am learning Android and trying to know about Android calling Facebook.I downloaded Facebook SDK 3.6 and created the project and invoked that library.

In the below Java code the below lines are striked out.  (And it says those lines are deprecated)

First 2 imports AysncFacebookrunner is striked out,

```
// Instance of Facebook Class
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private Facebook facebook = new Facebook(APP_ID);
    private AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner;
```

Even the private Facebook facebook = new Facebook(APP_ID); statement also Right hand side of Facebook is striked out and also its says Deprecated.I saw the solution is upgrade from 2.0 to 3.0,  but i am already using 3.6 SDK Version.

I used the below code.

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-facebook-connect-tutorial/

Is there any other source code availble for connecting android with facebook using FACEBOOK SDK 3.6 Version?

Comment: Please check the answer below, and if it has solved your problem them please do accept it, thanks.

Comment: Once i tried i will accept that

Comment: Have you tried the code described in my answer ?

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't contain Post wall. Could you please let me know how to post the message to Facebook

Comment: The Second link in the answer demonstrates that (Post on FB wall Using 3.0 SDK), please check it.

Comment: Your Question has been solved and you are on stuck on another problem, i recommend you to please accept the answer. So that other people also facilitate from this. Thank You.

Comment: There is a tick-mark below the down arrow, you need to click that in order to accept the answer. Thank You.

Comment: Where is the answer?